# Generate link from form field Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to input a phone number into a form element, and generate a clickable `TEL:` link.
When a user inputs a number, it should display a clickable link with that number in the paragraph below.
Example, if you enter 800-888-8888 it would generate html code: `<a href="tel:800-888-8888">800-888-8888</a>`

```
<form>
  <label>Phone Number</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" >
</form>
<p id="telLink">This text will be replaced by the link</p>
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add the JavaScript code you're having issues with... And PS, you don't need `<form>` if all you need is to plain-generate a HTML output - which on itself seems like half of your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form>
  <label>Phone Number</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" onchange="generateLink(this.value)">
</form>
<p id="telLink">This text will be replaced by the link</p>

<script>
   function generateLink(number) {
      if (number.length) {
         document.getElementById('telLink').innerHTML = `<a href="tel:${number}">${number}</a>`
      } else {
         document.getElementById('telLink').innerHTML = 'This text will be replaced by the link'
      }
   }
</script>
```

**Edited to correct the closing `a` tag

Answer (score 2):

You can set an event listener on the input, and change the `innerHTML` of `#telLink` accordingly:

```js
const telLink = document.getElementById("telLink");
const phoneInput = document.getElementById("phone");

phoneInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
  const phone = e.currentTarget.value;
  const link = phone ? `<a href="tel:${phone}">${phone}</a>` : '';
  telLink.innerHTML = link;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Phone Number</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="phone" >
</form>
<p id="telLink"></p>
```

Comment: Even if `Event.target` is correct *in this specific case* - `Event.currentTarget` should be used - just for muscle memory. Use `Event.target` in those rare cases and when you really, really know what you're doing.